# How display tiles by using earth plugin in browser?

Tags: tiles

I was using MapTiler to generate tiles for my maps, and everything is great. But I have problems with displaying those tiles in 3D version by using earth plugin. The data which gave me MapTiler was with files but for API 2, but I want to use now API 3 version.

All works fine with using maps, but I cannot display tiles by using earth plugin.

Please give me some examples, if anyone had to do something with this subject.

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the tiles with the Google Earth profile in MapTiler. Then you will get even a sample viewer using the GE browser plugin.

Here is a step by step guide:

http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/kml-superoverlay/